# Developing Node.js application remotely using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, node.js, remote-access

I have a remote machine running Ubuntu, where a node.js environment is setup. I want to develop a node.js application using eclipse on my local machine with the dev environment on the remote machine. What is the way to configure the same in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at standard Eclipse Remote System Explorer
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/remote-system-explorer-ssh-telnet-ftp-and-dstore-protocols

It will be just like remote console and file manager.
Though it has some integration e.g. extension to all wizard to create project on remote system, I have not tried. Create an issue if you want to discuss further https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/